# I dont want to insert the PK val.But - Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Employees' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: entity-framework

I am using the Entity Framework to update my database.
The Employee table has an employeeId primary key field.
When I instantiate an employee object, the employeeId defaults to zero.
I want to insert the employee object into the database, ignoring the primary key value of zero.
Yet I get this exception;
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Employees' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
What should I be doing to stop this?

```
    public void Add()
    {
        using (SHPContainerEntities db = new SHPContainerEntities())
        {
            // Set default values
            this.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            // Start date now
            this.SHP_UserRoleId = db.SHP_UserRoles.Where(x => x.RoleName == "Employee").Single().UserRoleId;
            // Default user role is "Employee". This can be changed later.
            this.DepartmentId = 1;
            // This is a temporary fix.
            db.AddToEmployees(this);
            //db.Employees.AddObject(this);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem.
I updated the database and I forgot to update my edmx file to reflect that change.

Comment: You updated your database and edmx file HOW, specifically?  I am getting this same error, but your "answer" doesn't really help me.

Comment: I updated the database via SQL Server management studio - I am sure I could have also done so in Visual Studio server explorer. In Visual studio I opened the .edmx object (in my case SHP.edmx) where I can see all of the tables and relationships. I right-click on an empty part of the pane and I select "Update Model from Database"